# Cakephp overide Controller constructer

Tags: oop, overriding, cakephp-2.3

I would to override constroller constrcuter's like this :

```
class XControler extends AppController { 

   public $attr = null;  

   public __construct(){

      $this->attr = new YController();

   }

}
```

But when I do that I take error ! can you explain me why and how I do that with out using requestAction just OOP !

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are responsible for dealing with end user requests. Each controller action should have a view, and normally you would not want to access the methods from YController inside XController.

What you want to achieve can be done this way:

**XController.php**

```
App::uses('YController', 'Controller');

class XController extends AppController {

    public $attr;
    public $uses = array('Person');

    public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
        $this->attr = new YController();
        parent::__construct($request, $response);
    }

    public function method1() {
        // you can now call methods from YController:
        $this->attr->Ymethod1();
    }

}
```

**YController.php**

```
class YController extends AppController {

    public function Ymethod1() {
        // ....
    } 

}
```

---

However, the business logic should be inside Models or Components. This is the proper way to share methods between more controllers.

So your XController should look like:

```
class XController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Model1');

    public function action1() {
        $this->Model1->method1();
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to explain the code you posted. Answers containing only code are often not very helpful.

Comment: I added the code for the __construct function, because the code from the question is incomplete. Can you tell us more about why you need to use a controller in another controller?

Comment: l want to call methods which existe in other contrôleurs so when i create controller i attached required controllers like attributes

Comment: What type of functions from YController will you need inside XController? Can those functions be placed in models or components? Controller actions shouldn't be used by other controllers.

Comment: I placed a buissness methods in YController class , so I would like to call it from XController , that's why !!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please let us know if that is clear. You could also paste some of the business logic methods that you think belong in controllers, if you still think you neeed that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedbak , I had tested this code but i detected error : empty attrbute in XController class !!!

Comment: You need to be more specific about what code you are testing and what PHP error you are getting